# Get 5 business days before today

Tags: javascript

I need to get an array of 5 business days from the current day.

Today is: 06/04/2018

The output i need is:

```
{
     0: 06/01/2018, //fri.
     1: 05/31/2018, //thur.
     2: 05/30/2018, //wed.
     3: 05/29/2018, //tue.
     4: 05/28/2018 //mon.
};
```

This is my code and current output:

```
{
     0: business_day_from_date(1),//sun. i don't want weekends
     1: business_day_from_date(2),//sat i don't want weekends
     2: business_day_from_date(3),//fri.
     3: business_day_from_date(4),//thur.
     4: business_day_from_date(5),//wed.
}


function business_day_from_date(daysAgo){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysAgo);
    return date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear();
}
```

Business days are:

- monday
- tuesday
- wednesday
- thursday
- friday

Comment: Maybe you can figure something out that uses this date method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Comment: I would suggest a `while` loop to iterate `n`-times, use `date.getDay()` and increment or skip values containing Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```js
function business_day_from_date(daysAgo, date) {//pass date in
  const result = [];
  const d = new Date(date);//do not mutate date passed in
  while (daysAgo > 0) {//while we have not enough work days
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);//take one day of the copy of the date passed in
    if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6) {//if not sat or sun
      daysAgo--;//we found one
      result.push(new Date(d));//add copy of the found one to result
    }
  }
  return result.reverse();//oldest to newest
}
function formatDate(date){
  return (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear()
}
console.log(
  "date passed in:",formatDate(new Date()),
  business_day_from_date(3, new Date()).map(
    function(date){return formatDate(date);}
  )
)
```

Using daysAgo to go back days from the date passed in and get all work days until but not including date passed in.

```js
function business_day_from_date(daysAgo, date) {//pass date in
  const result = [];
  const d = new Date(date);//do not mutate date passed in
  const end = new Date(d);
  d.setDate(d.getDate()-daysAgo);//go back the daysAgo value
  while (d.getTime()<end.getTime()) {//while we have not passed date passed in
    if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6) {//if not sat or sun
      daysAgo--;//we found one
      result.push(new Date(d));//add copy of the found one to result
    }
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);//add a day
  }
  return result;//oldest to newest, use .reverse to get newest to oldest
}
function formatDate(date){
  return (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear()
}
console.log(
  "date passed in:",formatDate(new Date()),
  business_day_from_date(3, new Date()).map(
    function(date){return formatDate(date);}
  )
)
```

Comment: What i like about this answer is that i can easily change the amount of days i need. What i don't like is the while loop ( i think it should be a for loop ). :) This is definitely the answer i was looking for! thanks man

Comment: @CodeofGod I used `daysAgo` as amount of work days but if you'd like days ago from passed date and get all work days then that's easy enough, I'll add that. Instead of while you could recursively call a function but since we're mutating a date to get the result I think it's fine to do it like this.

Comment: @CodeofGod Updated answer to return dates oldest to newest and other use case for `daysAgo`

Comment: This worked perfectly the way i needed it to :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```js
function getArrayOfLastNBusinessDays(N) {
  var myArray = [];
  var i = 0;
  var daysAgo = 1;
  while (i < N) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysAgo);
   var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
   if (dayOfWeek !== 6 && dayOfWeek !== 0) {
     myArray.push(date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear());
     i++;
   }
   daysAgo++;
  }

  return myArray;
}

console.log(getArrayOfLastNBusinessDays(5));
```